# Fetching Google Docs Spreadsheet Data using PHP

Tags: php, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to fetch the data from a google docs spreadsheet and I think this should work (also seen similar code in another similar question on here) but the response I get is:

`Moved Temporarily
The document has moved here.` with the link to `here` being:

`https://www.google.com/a/4playtheband.co.uk/ServiceLogin?service=wise&continue=https://docs.google.com/a/4playtheband.co.uk/spreadsheet/pub?hl%3Den_US%26hl%3Den_US%26key%3D0AuJb1YSvmVn5dGdvUzU2QUJHUGdaTEZNbVI4dVJ6eHc%26single%3Dtrue%26gid%3D0%26output%3Dcsv%26ndplr%3D1&followup=https://docs.google.com/a/4playtheband.co.uk/spreadsheet/pub?hl%3Den_US%26hl%3Den_US%26key%3D0AuJb1YSvmVn5dGdvUzU2QUJHUGdaTEZNbVI4dVJ6eHc%26single%3Dtrue%26gid%3D0%26output%3Dcsv%26ndplr%3D1&hl=en_US&passive=true&go=true`

I don't know if the problem is to do with the docs in question being used inside Google Apps but I have set the spreadsheet to be public and I copied the link it provided when I went to `Share` and exported it as a csv.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$url='https://docs.google.com/a/4playtheband.co.uk/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_US&hl=en_US&key=0AuJb1YSvmVn5dGdvUzU2QUJHUGdaTEZNbVI4dVJ6eHc&single=true&gid=0&output=csv';

if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $totalrows = count($data);
        for ($row=0; $row<=$totalrows; $row++)
        {
            echo $data[$row];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

If it might be an issue I am actually trying to place the fetched data inside a facebox and it seems to be working except for the actual spreadsheet data not appearing since the error message I mentioned earlier actually appears inside the facebox.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The code seems to work perfectly fine when the spreadsheet is created within my personal google account and not the account that I use for Google Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by firstly using a spreadsheet inside my own google account and not google apps and by then using the following code:

```
<div id="faqSection">
<!-- The FAQs are inserted here -->
<p>

<?php
// link to Google Docs spreadsheet
$url='google docs spreadsheet url';

// open file for reading
if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $totalrows = count($data);
        for ($row=0; $row<=$totalrows; $row++)
        {
            // only print out even rows, i.e. the questions
            // the second if is to avoid blank divs from being printed out
            // which was a bug I was experiencing
            if (($row % 2 == 0) && (strlen($data[$row])>0))
            {
                $answer = $row + 1;
                echo '<dt><span class="icon"></span>'.$data[$row].'</dt><dd>'.$data[$answer].'</dd>';
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a HTTP 302 status code, which means you should follow the link to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks but I'm sure I tried using that new url but it just returns the same message. I just tried it again and can confirm nothing changes :(

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the URL redirects by issuing a 302 and fopen can't follow HTTP redirects. I would think using curl bindings would resolve this issue.

Also consider using the Zend GData library as a high level API for Google Docs.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html

Comment: thanks but I am not using Zend unfortunately. I will look up what you suggested, thanks.