# Make bar chart using canvas.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

Hello I am new  to JavaScript but having difficulty with the generation of charts using the canvas.js library.  The step that I am failing to replicate is the example on canvasjs website https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/create-charts-from-csv/ for generating a chart using a csv document.  Will I have to approach differently since I am hosting from google sheets?

My current code is:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>TEst</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){
    var dataPoints = [];

    function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {
        var dataPoints = csvLines = points = [];
        csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);

        for (var i = 0; i < csvLines.length; i++)
            if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
                points = csvLines[i].split(",");
                dataPoints.push({ 
                    x: parseFloat(points[0]), 
                    y: parseFloat(points[1])        
            });
        }
        return dataPoints;
    }

    //Replace text file's path according to your requirement.
    $.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12o9ekzln8KB3Uyg2fVou6UtIUlrC5GC973Ttk6GsjKs/edit?usp=sharing",function(data) {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
            text: "Chart from CSV",
            },
            data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: getDataPointsFromCSV(data)
        }]
        });

        chart.render();

    });
    }

        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <p>it worked:</p>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I inspect with chrome I get the following error.

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this without have a server running for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is already a good answer to this question, I added a link to the bottom of this answer.

It sounds like Google is not allowing you to load the data from their website.
Try replacing your **dataPoints: getDataPointsFromCSV(data)** with some example data from chart.js's site to make sure the rest of your code is working.

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. with github sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926391/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-wi)